# Why does my label in interface builder refuse to connect to my code?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, storyboard, iboutlet

Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FgLp.png

The prototype cell is of the class "ArticleCell", but it won't let me hook up the label to it. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that your label is a subview of the cell?

Comment: C'mon, why not just make this in code instead of messing with IB? Whatever you try it won't work as expected anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an outlet for a label in the view controller's class, you can only do that in a subclass of UITableViewCell. It doesn't work to have the outlet in the ViewController class because that label could exist 1000s of times if you have a heavily populated table. Either you need to make it a static cell (in which case the label will only exist once, and you can give it an outlet), or you should access with with the viewWithTag property (i.e. set its tag in interface builder, then access it in code later on).